# hackintosh install

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, macos

I successfully setup MacOS High Sierra in `qemu` running in Linux. I followed https://github.com/foxlet/macOS-Simple-KVM which is a great GitHub repo.

My machine boots fine to the recovery. I have formatted the disk and everything but when running the reinstall it errors out and says that it can't contact Apple's recovery server.

I reset the date with `date -u ""`. I believe this GitHub script passes my Linux Wi-Fi network interface through to `eth0`, because I can access the internet from the internet utilities in the recovery. I can ping my website (just because that's a domain I know of), and the `eth0` network appears connected.

What could I try next?

Answer (score 0):

I decided to keep trying again this afternoon and it went to the software agreement first try. My only guess is that apples servers were temporarily down or inaccessible.